# Notify user on news service update

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am developing a toast notification news service.
I can successfully parse and display the first time - on the Android application screen - the xml file (with the news) and the toast with the news one by one.
The xml file file is pulled from a server where I publish news hourly.
But, I need to notify the user, with the toast (possibly?) when there is latest news, in which case the rss file is being updated. 
So I need to display more news at some point later.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Notifications through the NotificationManager. It is the best way to notify the user and invite him to open a more complete view to have more details.